# what is the difference between the Fraction class constructor and from_float in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, fractions, python-fractions

I am using the class constructor Fraction to create fractions.
What is the difference between using the Fraction class constructor and from_float method when creating fractions from floating-point numbers?

I tested it with different numbers and I got same answers.
for instance:

```
from fractions import Fraction

f1 = Fraction(0.3)
f2 = Fraction.from_float(0.3)

print(f1)  # Output: 5404319552844595/18014398509481984
print(f2)  # Output: 5404319552844595/18014398509481984
```

Comment: Did you read [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction.from_float)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fractions.html#fractions.Fraction):

> *Changed in version 3.2:* The `Fraction` constructor now accepts `float` and `decimal.Decimal` instances.

> **Note:** From Python 3.2 onwards, you can also construct a `Fraction` instance directly from a `float`.

In other words, in Python < 3.2, you *had* to use `Fraction.from_float` to construct a `Fraction` from a `float`. Since 3.2 this has become unnecessary, but still exists probably so as not to break backwards compatibility. You may also want to use it for more explicit type checking, as `Fraction.from_float` would raise an error if you passed some other type, which the `Fraction` constructor might silently accept and *potentially* lead to subtle bugs.

Answer (score 1):

Reading the implementation you can see that after type checking, the function [`from_float`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/fractions.py#L292) gets numerator and denominator with the same method as [`Fraction(float)`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/main/Lib/fractions.py#L230) does.
That is, by calling `as_integer_ratio`.